# Need some help for DrawerNavigatorItems V3 react-native 0.60.4

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code, react-navigation

I've got this error but I can't find from where it is coming.

Error:

[image]

Here is my DrawerNavigator screen:

```
import React from "react";
import { Platform, Dimensions } from "react-native";
import { createDrawerNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";

import HomeScreen from '../components/HomeScreen';
import AboutScreen from '../components/AboutScreen';
import Count from '../components/CountScreen';

const WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const DrawerConfig = {
  drawerWidth: WIDTH*80,
};

const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  About:{
    screen: AboutScreen
  },
  Count:{
    screen: Count
  },

  },
  DrawerConfig 
);

export default createAppContainer(DrawerNavigator);
```

I have also StackNavigator if this can help.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';
import DrawerNavigator from './DrawerNavigatorNew';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: LoginScreen,
  Drawer: DrawerNavigator,
});


export default createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

If you need more screens I will add them.

Comment: Please update with import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

Answer (score 0):

You can try add braces.

And wrap the container only once.

```js
const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Home:{
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  About:{
    screen: AboutScreen
  },
  Count:{
    screen: Count
  }
  },
  { 
   drawerWidth: WIDTH*80
  } 
);

export default DrawerNavigator;
```

Comment: @YoanIvanov wrap the container only once. updated my answer

Comment: Does 'WIDTH' get the value correctly? Check through the console.

Comment: I can't see that error in the console, neither where is located

Comment: The area causing the error should be deleted and the correct 'WIDTH' value should be obtained.